# Someone, anyone, somebody, everybody. Are those 3rd or 1st person?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, third-person-singular

Is there any rule or a reminder I can use? 
I've got confused all the time.

Is it "Someone say" or "Someone says"?
Is it "everybody say" or "Anybody says"?
And the most confusing for me is "Nobody Speak" or "Nobody speaks?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of these terms behave as if they were singular.

If you are using a verb in the present simple, you use third person singular:

> If someone **says** that the earth is flat, nobody will believe them.
>   If somebody **says** that the earth is flat, nobody will believe them.
>   Everybody **says** that the earth is round.
>   If anybody **says** that the earth is flat, nobody will believe them
>   Nobody **says** that the earth is flat.

Note that, in the "nobody will believe them" clause, **believe** is not a third person plural but a bare infinitive because it follows **will**.

If you tell somebody to do something, you use an imperative which is the same as a bare infinitive:

> Someone **call** for an ambulance!
>   Everybody **keep** quiet!